# How to handle empty table from Glue's data catalog in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue

I'd like to execute SparkSQL on SageMaker by AWS Glue, but haven't succeeded.

What I want to do is *parameterizing* Glue job, so I want it acceptable to access empty tables. However, when the method `glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog` is provided with an empty table, it raises an error.

Here's a code what raises an error:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

df1 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database = "<glue's database name>",
    table_name = "<glue's table name>",  # I want here to be parameterized
    transformation_ctx = "df1"
)
df1 = df1.toDF()  # Here raises an Error
df1.createOrReplaceTempView('tmp_table')
df_sql = spark.sql("""SELECT ...""")
```

And this is the error:

`Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.`

Is it impossible to use an empty table as an input to DynamicFrame? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you confirm if the table is partitioned and if yes then is it using hive style partitioning i.e, year=2018/month=10 or just 2018/10 in s3 ?

Comment: Can you check for `df1.rdd.isEmpty()` before `.toDF()`?

Comment: @bdcloud The table is partitioned, and the style is like `year=2018/month=10` in s3. I indicate a partition by `push_down_predicate` option in `from_catalog` method. As neither works, I thought this isn't the core of the problem.

Comment: @PavloPravdiukov Thx for the comment! What I really hope is SparkSQL accepts an empty table and works as well as Hive does with an empty table. But if it doesn't work, I'll use `isEmpty` and return immediately.

Comment: Can you explain why you are trying to pass empty tables and what is the use case that you are trying to solve by passing empty tables?

Comment: it may be due to your partition schema is different from glue table schema. Delete Glue table and recreate it by  running crawler with option `Update all new and existing partitions with metadata from the table.`

Comment: @bdcloud I'd like to create a AWS Glue's pyspark template that accepts parameters. The parameters specify tables used by SparkSQL. It may happen that the specified tables are empty and I want to accept it. (More precisely, the Glue job calculates data depending on yesterday's data, so when it runs at first, yesterday's data must be empty).

Comment: Any update on the question? I am running into exactly the same issue due to job book marking.

Answer (score -2):

```py
df1 = df1.toDF()  # Here raises an Error
```

Replace this line with:

```py
dynamic_df = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df1, glueContext, 'sample_job')  # Load pyspark df to dynamic frame
```